# Why would people think this question was a duplicate?

Tags: discussion

The more recent question:

> [Is this correct? "One of the things that makes him great is..."](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/232255/is-this-correct-one-of-the-things-that-makes-him-great-is)
>
> ```
> One of the things that makes him great is he brings it every night.
> ```
>
> I'm pretty sure it should be "that make him", because one of the
>   things is referring to a lot of things ...but I always see native
>   American speakers say it with an s.
>
> Another example:
>
> ```
> This is one of the responsibilities that comes with greatness and he understands that.
> ```
>
> They always use the word with s even though it's grammatically
>   incorrect.

The question it is supposed to be a duplicate of:

> ["One of them was/were you"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/46040/one-of-them-was-were-you)
>
> If I am talking to somebody about a certain group of people in the
>   third person, and then want to refer to the person I am talking with
>   as one of those people, which do I say?
>
> ```
> One of them were you
>
> One of them was you.
> ```

Surely this is a mistake and the more recent question should be reopened?

Comment: I’ve voted to reöpen, but I shall also probably vote to rec̈lose as a duplicate of one of the related questions that [is ¦ are] listed below. :)

Comment: @tchrist Öh ÿöü äñd ÿöür ümłäütš.

Comment: @DanBron T̈ḧëÿ’r̈ë d̈ïæ̈r̈ës̈ës̈, än̈d̈ Ï c̈än̈ p̈üẗ ẗḧëm̈ äẗöp̈ ẅḧäẗs̈öëv̈ër̈ l̈ëẗẗër̈ Ï p̈l̈ëäs̈ë, ẗöö. :)

Comment: @tchrist: Oh, my, you're quite the character. A combining one, I suspect.

Comment: @tchrist D̈̈ö̈n̈̈’̈̈ẗ̈ g̈̈ë̈ẗ̈ ö̈ü̈ẗ̈ ö̈f̈̈ ḧ̈ä̈n̈̈d̈̈ n̈̈ö̈ẅ̈!̤̤̤̈̈̈

Answer (score 4):

I agree that it was improperly closed as a duplicate of a question which it is not in fact a duplicate of.

However, I would be a wee bit surprised if this question had not already been answered here under some other guise.

### Related Questions

- [“It’s one of the best films that has/have ever been made.”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/184634)
- [“One of the children who was” vs. “one of the children who were”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/185714)
- [Subject-Verb Agreement with “Who”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/200208)
- [One of the many things that (have or has)? affected me was](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/130633)
- [“One of those is flags”](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/37299)
- [Can you guess what one of his tasty ingredients were?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/177097)
- [Singular or plural noun in a sentence after using both in a related conjunction?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/12628)

Comment: OK fair enough. Then close it as a duplicate of whichever of those question you deem most exhaustively answered.

Comment: @Cerberus Well, they’re mostly lame answers.

Comment: Then perhaps they ought to be closed as duplicates of the recent question?